# Navigating website with application

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, html

I'm looking to make a C# application to automate some processes for me.  One of which would be navigating a few websites that I frequent, such as grooveshark.  I'd like my application to be able to log me into the website and search for/play a song.

I've done some googling on the topic and came across something called selenium.  I was wondering if this was the best tool for what I would like to accomplish or if there is another option that would be a suit my needs better?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium will do fine, unless the sites use Flash. If they do, you are pretty much stuck.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

I would read up on Selenium and come back when you have a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

In order to automate your process , you can use `Microsoft Test Manager` , who is tool about `testing and generating code`

On Microsoft Test Manager 2012 , for example  you have new functionnality such as `Exploratory Test`, the process is you explore your application and generate your test.

Link :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191621.aspx

After creating your tests, you can generate Coded UI Test and include in your build process

Note : you must use Team Foundation Server or Service in order interact with Test Case WorkItem

Answer (score 0):

If you have Visual studio Premium or greater I would suggest Coded UI. I would also suggest CUITe http://cuite.codeplex.com/ as it simplifies the code.

Answer (score 0):

It definately depends on what your automation is going to be able to. I don't know *Selenium* at all. I think it's for recording certain actions on a website in a certain order. Though you will only be able to automate the process as far as the website (the actual client) capabilities offer.

If you'd like to build some different, more advanced behaviour the client doesn't provide yet, you'd need to build your own client. That'd need some backwards engeneering. That'd be the case for e.g. automating browser games. Usually a browser game client doesn't provide scanning certain amounts of players and automatically comparing them to your own player profile, so building this feature on your own would be the only possible solution.